# How to multithread a client and server in the same .py , but on different ports

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, chat, python-multithreading

I want to make a chat program on Python, such that I can send as well as receive data.
I was thinking that I could have multiple threads running, one for the client and server each.
My Question is
How do I have multiple threads running in one file, for two classes?

My Current code:

```
from socket import *
from threading import Thread

class Server(Thread):
    def __init__(self,host,port,user):
        self.port = port
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.bufsize = 1024
        self.addr = (host,port)

        self.socket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind(self.addr)
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.socket.listen(5)
        while True:
            print 'Waiting for connection..'
            client, caddr = self.socket.accept()
            print 'Connected To',caddr

            data = client.recv(self.bufsize)
            if not data:
                continue
            print data         


class Client(Thread):
    def __init__(self,host,port,user):
        self.port = port
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.bufsize = 1024
        self.addr = (host,port)

        self.socket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM)
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.socket.connect(self.addr)
        while True:
            data = raw_input('> ')
            if not data:
                continue
            data = user+' said : '+data
            tcpClient.send(data)

host = ''
p1 = int(raw_input('Enter Port 1 : '))
p2 = int(raw_input('Enter Port 2 : '))
user = raw_input('Enter Your user: ').strip()

client = Client(host,p1,user)
server = Server(host,p2,user)

client.start()
server.start()
```

My current error msg:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python2.7 For Chintoo\lib\threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\karuna\Desktop\Jython\Python\My Modules\Network\Chat.py", line 41, in run
    self.socket.connect(self.addr)
  File "C:\Python2.7 For Chintoo\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

Comment: Have you tried the `threading` module?

Comment: These are very typical examples Google throws up http://www.newthinktank.com/2010/11/python-2-7-tutorial-pt-18-chat-server/ video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, simply start multiple threads:

```
from threading import Thread

class Foo(Thread):
     def __init__(self):
         Thread.__init__(self)
         self.keepRunning = True
     def run(self):
         while self.keepRunning:
            print "running in thread", self

import time
if __name__ == "__main__":
     mythread1 = Foo()
     mythread2 = Foo()
     mythread1.start()
     mythread2.start()
     time.sleep(10) # and let the 2 threads to their work
     mythread1.keepRunning = False
     mythread2.keepRunning = False
```

Comment: Received an error on implementation  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\karuna\Desktop\Jython\Python\My Modules\Network\Chat.py", line 54, in <module>
    client = Client(host,p1,name)
  File "C:\Users\karuna\Desktop\Jython\Python\My Modules\Network\Chat.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.name = name
AssertionError: Thread.__init__() not called`

Comment: that was just a sketch; i updated the code so that it actually works :-)

Comment: you are inheriting from `Thread` and fail to call the `__init__` method of the superclass. but this i only know because of telepathy mode, as you haven't posted the relevant code for that.

Answer (score 2):

The threading module should be just what you need. http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

```
from socket import *
from threading import Thread

class Server(Thread):
    def __init__(self,host,port,name):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.port = port
        self.host = host
        self.name = name
        self.bufsize = 1024
        self.addr = (host,port)

        self.socket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind(self.addr)

    def run(self):
        self.socket.listen(5)
        while True:
            print 'Waiting for connection..'
            client, caddr = self.socket.accept()
            print 'Connected To',caddr

            data = client.recv(self.bufsize)
            if not data:
                continue
            print data         


class Client(Thread):
    def __init__(self,host,port,name):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.port = port
        self.host = host
        self.name = name
        self.bufsize = 1024
        self.addr = (host,port)

        self.socket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM)

    def run(self):
        invalid = True
        while invalid:
            try:
                invalid = False
                self.socket.connect(self.addr)
            except:
                invalid = True

        while True:
            data = raw_input('> ')
            if not data:
                continue
            data = name+' said : '+data
            tcpClient.send(data)

host = ''
p1 = int(raw_input('Enter Port 1 : '))
p2 = int(raw_input('Enter Port 2 : '))
name = raw_input('Enter Your Name: ').strip()


server = Server(host,p2,name)
client = Client(host,p1,name)

server.start()
client.start()

server.join()
```

Also for some reasons, you should not use the old style class in python and at least inherit from object like this if you create simple class

class Something(object):
    ....

Comment: Same error as with [@umlaeute's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14894918/1931274#comment20889013_14894918)

Comment: Your error is fixed, you have to call the init method of the thread class

Comment: Btw, the name will be set as the name of the thread also... in that case if you want to have thread named differently you should use a different name for your thread

Comment: yes and you can pass any parameter you want to the Thread.__init__ just as written in the docs.

Comment: Get an exception on running the new script: `Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python2.7 For Chintoo\lib\threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\karuna\Desktop\Jython\Python\My Modules\Network\Chat.py", line 41, in run
    self.socket.connect(self.addr)
  File "C:\Python2.7 For Chintoo\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24568/discussion-between-loic-faure-lacroix-and-schoolboy)

Comment: @Schoolboy: would you mind adding additional information into your question rather than filling the "comments" with error-messages that do not relate to any actual code?